# How to set src of html from flask app for an audio file

Tags: html, flask, audio

My flask app generates some audio dynamically and I am trying to pass it to the client for autoplay. This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Paadas</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Welcome to Padaas</h1>
   <audio controls autoplay>
     <source src="{{source}}" type="audio/wav">
     Your browser does not support the audio element.
   </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my python app:

```
# Importing flask module in the project is mandatory
# An object of Flask class is our WSGI application.
from flask import Flask, send_file, Response, render_template, redirect
# Response, send_file, after_this_request
import random
import time
import wave
import io

# Flask constructor takes the name of
# current module (__name__) as argument.
app = Flask(__name__)
 
# The route() function of the Flask class is a decorator,
# which tells the application which URL should call
# the associated function.
# ‘/’ URL is bound with index() function.
@app.route('/')
def paadas():
    #Approach 2
    def generate(files):
        with wave.open(files[0], 'rb') as f:
            params = f.getparams()
            frames = f.readframes(f.getnframes())
        
        for file in files[1:]:
            with wave.open(file, 'rb') as f:
                frames += f.readframes(f.getnframes())
        
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        with wave.open(buffer, 'wb') as f:
            f.setparams(params)
            f.writeframes(frames)
        
        buffer.seek(0)
        return buffer.read()

    files = []
    number = random.randint(1,10)
    files.append("../numbers/" + str(number) + ".wav")
    times = random.randint(1,10)
    files.append("../times/" + str(times) + ".wav")
    return render_template("index.html", source=generate(files))
 
# main driver function
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    # run() method of Flask class runs the application
    # on the local development server.
    app.run()
```

However when the page is rendered on load, there is no audio getting played and the audio control is disabled for playing. I am not sure about my line of code

```
    return render_template("index.html", source=generate(files))
```

above. You can also checkout my code structure at: https://github.com/sameermahajan/PaadasMLFlaskApp in case there are any issues with it.

Comment: When I run the code I'm getting errors because the `generate` function is trying to read .wav files that aren't there. Do these .wav files already exist on your machine?

Comment: Questions should be self-contained here, they shouldn’t be reliant on external sources to illustrate a problem since those links frequently change and reduce value for future visitors to this question. Please follow the stackoverflow guidelines for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: These wav files are in the repo pointed to by my question now

Answer (score 1):

You're close, you just need to change the line

```py
return render_template("index.html", source=generate(files))
```

to

```py
return Response(generate(files))
```

Then, in `index.html`, change

```html
<source src="{{source}}" type="audio/wav">
```

to

```html
<source src="{{ url_for('paadas') }}" type="audio/wav">
```

The `/paadas` route serves a response with a .wav file and the `/` route serves `index.html`, where the .wav file is embedded using the `/paadas` route as the source.

Working solution:

[image: Working solution]

Comment: it does not work even after I added mimetype='audio/wav to your proposed Response statement above. The control does not return to index.html. See my other related question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76280394/dynamically-constructing-client-side-content-from-server-in-flask

Comment: Also where is 'paadas' defined whose url you are referring above?

Comment: It is working as expected on my machine. I will update my answer with a screen capture. You defined the 'paadas' route with this line: @app.route('/paadas')

Comment: It would be helpful if you included some additional information other than "it does not work"

Comment: I see the confusion. I want my paadas to start right away and don't want to switch to /paadas route for that. The code that I have put here is old but updated in the repo. Will update it here as well.

Comment: As you can see in the screen capture I have added, it is working at the home route, not the paadas route

Comment: but the home route should have other objects like buttons from index.html ...

Comment: Yes, you can update `index.html` to include whatever you want. Right now, in the code you provided, it just has the title and the audio player.

Comment: I think I got what you are doing (You are actually hitting '/' route). The only thing remaining is now to autoplay the audio. I have already specified 'autoplay' in my HTML but it doesn't seem to work. I have to click on play in the controls to play it which is what you are also doing as I can see in your recording.

Comment: I missed the part where you wanted to autoplay the audio. It looks like that is quite difficult to do in modern browsers. You'll need to either have the user interact with your page first before the audio can be played OR the audio must be muted. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#autoplay_availability

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think the Python side is working fine. I think the issue comes from the html side and the way you are rendering to the page. The issue lies within the source tag. Flask is unable to resolve the url the way you currently have it.

Try changing this:

```
<source src="{{source}}" type="audio/wav">
```

To this:

```
<source src="{{ url_for('static', filename=source) }}" type="audio/wav">
```

And here is a little light reading about url_for:
[Geeks for Geeks: url_for](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flask-url-helper-function-flask-url_for/)

Comment: I would like to mention that this assumes the file is placed in the static folder which it looks like it is

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I will try it out on my system when I get to it and get back accordingly.

Comment: It did not work. I see error "GET /static/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - I was hoping that the python code puts the file there when it returns. Python code just returns the stream and I don't know how to specify the filename on client to put the content there. Hence the question. I see some posts stating that it is not possible.